# Are all traces of parametric curves dependent of the parameter?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

I was trying to plot the parametric curve

$(cos(t^{2}), sin(t^{2}), 0 )$ with some online graphing tool.

Shouldn't the trace of this curve be the same as a circle, with only difference being how fast the curves "runs" through the circle with respect to t?

Yet the trace of the function I get with these online tools have points all over the interior of the trace of a circle.

Is my assumption incorrect?

Comment: Your assumption is fully justified and correct. If your graphing tool gives you points inside the circle, there is something wrong, either with it, or with the way you keyed the formulas in.

Comment: @Archis: But this will only affect "when" the x,y coordinates achieve the values they receive when the parameter is linear won't it? the trig identity still hold so I should never have any points in the interior of a circle as long as the argument inside cos and sin are the same.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the curve should be on the $z=0$ axis.

I have attached the output from desmos, an online tool to plot graph.

It holds due to the identity of $\sin^2(t)+\cos^2(t)=1$, and hence $\sin^2(t^2)+\cos^2(t^2)=1$ holds as well.

[image]

Comment: Using wolfram alpha, what is the reason that they unable to plot the correct graph ?